# Relative URL's/paths in php

Tags: php

Hi this is the first time I am asking a question here.

I have a image src as

```
src="images//images/pixel.gif"
```

But I dont understand this double forward slashes (**//**) in the src.

Also what is the meaning of "**./**" and "**../**" in a relative file path like in below src:

```
src="./images/pixel.gif" 
src="../images/pixel.gif"
```

Comment: If anyone can explain it with reference to the situation like : you are accessing index.php from your www folder and you have a images folder in it and you want the src to include images from this folder.

Comment: For this exact situation, you can reference the image file relative to the php file with `images/pixel.gif`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An initial `/` means the root of the web page.

A directory entry with name `.` means the same directory. If it's at the beginning, it normally means something like "here" and mostly used to clarify that the path is relative to the present location.

A directory entry with name `..` means the parent directory. So, this means going up the directory tree.

If two or more `/` are consecutive, this cancels all previous path and replaces with the root of the web page.

That said,

`src="images//images/pixel.gif"` means `/images/pixel.gif` (directly at the root directory, a folder with name `images`, and then the file.

`src="./images/pixel.gif"` means a directory `images` inside the same directory where the loaded page resides (the one containing the reference to the image). Remember the *here* concept. You could also write directly `src="images/pixel.gif"`.

`src="../images/pixel.gif"` means going up to the parent directory in which resides the loaded page and then go down to a directory named `images`. Remember the *parent* concept.

Hope helped!

Comment: This helped but how come images//images means /images. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: The fact is that the `//` always cancels the previous path and replaces by the root. The file path behaves always that way, by definition. No chance to change that.

Comment: Is this only for php or all other languages like jsp, asp ??

Comment: @Md.Yusuf this applies to file management over linux(maybe windows too) server

Answer (score 5):

1. In most cases // will be same as /.
2. '.' means current directory and '..' means parent directory.

   /app/test/files/somefile.php,
     /app/test/files/another.php,
     /app/test/css/somecss.css

If you want to access somecss.css inside somefile.php and you don't know the absolute path from root of the application then you write.

../css/somecss.css -> Go to parent folder test then css folder and finally somecss.css file

Similarly if you want to access another.php you write

./another.php or simply another.php

Comment: you gave answer to my first question. But I don't understand the difference between ./ and ../ in a scenario that I have given in the comment already.

Comment: @Fèlix Galindo Allué: Thanks if the question was good then please rate it up.