# Relative URL issue

Tags: php, html

I will have multiple folders/modules to access common files. But accessing them seems to be  big deal for me!

I did gone through this link to understand the relative positioning and managed to solve some . But not all.  Reference: [Relative URL's/paths in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630570/relative-urls-paths-in-php)

My folder structure is as below:

Website runs on root folder:

`/(index|ajax).php`

and then the subfolders:

`/css/style.css`

`/img/*.(jpg|png|gif)`

`/inc/(header|footer).php`

`/js/*.js`

`/registration/(ajax|getsubjects|response|success).php`

Now, this is how I included files in the index.php page(this displays correctly, meaning, style,css,js,config all accessible)

```
<?php
include('inc/header.php');
?>

content here
<?php
include('inc/footer.php');
?>
```

This index page will have to fetch getsubjects.php, response.php and then finally land in success.php.

The success.php need some styling whereas the previous two were only for processing.

So now in the success.php I access header and footer as below:

```
include('../inc/header.php');
include('../inc/footer.php');
```

But this doesn't apply any styling!

inside header.php and footer I include files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

How should I include the files here please?

Comment: You say that the pages aren't being styled, but are the `link` and `script` tags present on the page and just not pointing at the right place? If they are then you have a HTML path issue and should look at the base path of your application (see my answer below). If they are not, then you've got a PHP issue and need to think about the paths for your includes (see below as well).

Comment: Easiest way is to open the developer tools in your browser of choice and checkout the `source` or the `console` for 404 errors (if the HTML paths are wrong, they'll trigger 404 errors).

Comment: @KevinNagurski, exactly I get the 404 error. I would like to use your suggestion include(_DIR_) but not sure how, studying it

Comment: One more suggestion... by using an `include` PHP will only issue a warning, which your environment might not be setup to display. Change to `require` instead... that'll make PHP fire off en error instead and really bring it your attention if something is amiss.

Comment: `__DIR__` is the path of the current PHP document, so you just need to append to that how to get to where you want to go. So, for example, to go 2 directories up and then into some others you might do this `require __DIR__ . '/../../some/other/place.php;`

Comment: @KevinNagurski I used include(__DIR__ . "../../inc/header.php"); inside success.php which is inside a sub folder to access the header.php.. I noticed in the console , the path it shows..main folder/subfolder/inc/header.php which is wrong

Comment: The official documentation is at http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php, but a quick google of `__DIR__` should do it as well

Comment: @KevinNagurski, but I want the path to be accessed is, main folder/inc/header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP-includes seem to be correct. But in your HTML you need to change the linking to the CSS and JS Files (maybe even to your images).

You could use absolute paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

the leading dot makes your paths relative to the HTML-Document, so if they are linked from a document in a subfolder, they point to a wrong location.

Comment: I did try like this but it still doesn't apply the styling for both sub directory and index.php file...I noticed this: If I use  href="../css/style.css" in header , it works for subdiretory file but not the index.php file..How to give standard link for both?

Comment: is your project in a subfolder located? if so, you have to add this folder to the path. Like: `/FOLDERNAME/OTHERFOLDERNAME/css/style.css`

Comment: my success.php file is inside sub folder.. from there how do I access header.php which is inside mainFolder/ inc/header.php

Comment: As i wrote, your php-includes are correct. You have to correct the paths inside your `header.php` and `footer.php` that are pointing to your CSS and JS files. One option is to use absolute paths (like: `/projectfolder/js/script.js` or: `http://www.yourserver.com/projectfolder/js/script.js`).

Comment: finally I solved by changing the header and footer path to absolute like this: http://localhost/main folder/css/style.css and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

`./css/style.css` means from current directory and would achieve the same result as `css/style.css`. The easiest answer is to determine what the base path of your application is and use that. For instance, if your application is running as `http://myapp.com`, then you could set all your front-end paths to `/css/style.css`. If your app runs in a subdirectory, such as `http://example.com/myapp`, then your paths would be `/myapp/css/style.css`.

This does not apply the same on the PHP side. For them, you should really use document-relative paths. Having a PHP file that you include in multiple places in your app, the contents of which having something like `include('../myDoc.php');`, can lead to complications as the path isn't based on the included document's path, but rather the including. So using document-relative paths, you get around this `include(__DIR__ . '/../myDoc.php');`. Just something to consider if your app grows.

Answer (score 0):

Including files with

```
<?php
    include("page1.php")
?>
```

put the code (or content) from `page1` **into** the caller page.

So you may have to detect from where your pages are called, or try absolute links (beginning by `/`)

I hope I answer you question correctly.